# MySQL db for online store

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a website where users can upload products to sell to one another.

What I currently have is a number of category's where each category has its own table in the database. The columns are `UserID`, `ProdID`, `Price`, `Description`, etc. but are all the same in each category table.

**Should I just have them all in the same table?** I ask because right now I'm finding it difficult to manage a way for the user to edit the uploaded products without searching every table.

Comment: unless your product categories have wildly different fields for each category, why not a single table for all categories?

Comment: Well my logic behind it was to separate them to different category tables so when searching for an item you could search just the category and browsing by category would all be easier. By putting them all in the one table it would make everything slower searching, browsing and editing the uploaded products.

Comment: Why dont you have another table which will have the uploaded record id and the product id it is related to. In that way you can get the product id and with it being separate table for each product, you can directly go to that table

Comment: unless you're dealing with millions of records, having an extra field in a single table to specify a category is not going to slow things down much, and the overhead of maintaining multiple tables in parallel is going to suck up a LOT of any savings you might gain

Answer (score 0):

A properly designed query can easily query against a properly indexed table with millions of rows with very rapid query results.  There is no reason you should have different tables for each category.

You just need to make sure you have proper indexes on the table for the columns you are going to filter, sort, or join on and that you utilize the indexes when making your query (i.e. only filter, sort, or join on indexed fields, and make sure you are not querying/sorting on derived values from the table that would prohibit index use).  You also need to make sure you have enough memory allocated such that the index can be fully resident in memory.

In general, you should always keep your schema as simple as possible:

- don't create separate tables for objects that have the same properties
- add only the attributes of an object to the table that are directly related to that object (i.e. normalize)
- express relations between objects using proper foreign keys (for one-to-many relations) or with join tables (many-to-many relations).
- use the proper field type to store the data you need to store (for example, use date/datetime fields for dates instead of integer timestamps or varchar)

Comment: We can get it with Northwind schema. It is one of a good example.